# Posting via email, where do I start troubleshooting?

Tags: posts, email

I host a site for a person that does everything via blackberry and wants to email posts to the site.  She has sent one post to the designated mailbox, but 24 hours later the post is still not showing.  Where do I start checking what is going wrong in the process?

Answer (score 1):

You're obviously posting it to a mailbox that WordPress is accessing, so check the mailbox that your friend has sent an email to, if the email is still in there then WP hasn't taken it out and thus your email settings in WP are probably wrong. If the email isn't in there your friend has probably sent it to the wrong address, not sent it at all or WP may not have read it correctly.

This is just the first step into determining the problem, tell us how you get on.

Comment: Those were the first things I checked.  There is email in the mailbox, so WordPress is not fetching it, I've triple checked the mail details(server, user name, password, port) all is correct.  Is there some kind of event log somewhere I can check for error messages?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this article](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_to_your_blog_using_email), you need to add an i-frame to your footer.php file that will call wp-mail.php whenever your site is loaded.  Apparently this file will process your inbox and create the posts.  This isn't mentioned in the documentation.  I've tried the setup, the mail got removed from the inbox, and the post got created, in a pending state.  Not quite what the config page says...

Comment: And the mail also did not get decoded...

Comment: Looks like post by email is something an admin needs first to really dig into, configure and fix a lot before it's working. I never did work with it, but I think to have such a feature working is something really nice.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check if wp-cron is running ? How often is your site is "visited" ?

I would suggest using the Postie Plugin, instead using the one that comes default. Postie has tons of features and you can add your post-email processing as a hook.

Comment: I'll give Postie a try, if you look at my answer, that's as far as I got.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great service called posterous - http://posterous.com/ - that makes this very easy, and your client will appreciate (it also does facebook, tweets, etc)

to post to WP by email uses xml-rpc - I have run into situations where certain hosts restrict this file in the security configuration, I would start there.

Comment: I think this suggestion is flawed, you don't know the client requirements, it's a WP Q&A site, not a Posterous sales pitch.

Comment: *@ILMV* - regarding the fact that there are problems with WP I think it's always worth to know about alternatives as well. This has nothing to do with a sales pitch.

Comment: Thanks for the alternatives, I use poseterous myself, but don't want to confuse the client with yet another option